# LibreOffice Base JDBC connection to Hive returns “Method not supported” when executing valid select statement

Tags: jdbc, hive, libreoffice, libreoffice-base

I'm trying to get LibreOffice's Base v5.1.4.2, running on Ubuntu v16.04 to connect to a Hive v1.2.1 database via JDBC. I added the following jars, downloaded from Maven Central, to LibreOffice's classpath ('Tools -> LibreOffice -> Advanced -> Class Path'):

```
hive-common-1.2.1.jar
hive-jdbc-1.2.1.jar
hive-metastore-1.2.1.jar
hive-service-1.2.1.jar
hadoop-common-2.6.2.jar
httpclient-4.4.jar
httpcore-4.4.jar
libthrift-0.9.2.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
```

I then restarted LibreOffice, opened Base, selected 'Connect to an existing database' -> 'JDBC' and set the following properties:

[image]

I entered the credentials and clicked the 'Test Connection' button, which returned a "the connection was established successfully" message. Great!

In the LibreOffice Base UI, the options under the 'Tables' panel were grayed out. The options in the queries tab were not, so I tried to connect to Hive.

[image]

The 'Use Wizard to Create Query' option prompts for a password and then returns "The field names from 'airline.on_time_performance' could not be retrieved."

[image: field names could not be retrieved]

The JDBC connection *is* able to connect to Hive and list the tables, though it seems to have problems retrieving the columns. When I try to execute a simple select statement, the 'Create Query in SQL View' option returns a somewhat cryptic "Method not supported" message:

[image: method not supported]

The error message is a bit vague. I suspect that I may be missing a dependency since I *am* able to connect to Hive from Java using JDBC.

I'm curious to know if anyone in the community has LibreOffice Base working with Hive. If so, what am I missing?

Comment: You're dozens of versions of the JDBC driver out of date here. I found 2.5.4 with not much trouble. Probably the one you're using is obsolete w.r.t. the Java JDBC version. Update.

Comment: Given the error "field names ... could not be retrieved" that version of the JDBC driver did not have support for `DatabaseMetaData.getColumns`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache JDBC driver reports *"Method not supported"* for **most** features, just because the Apache committers did not bother to handle the list of simple `yes/no` API calls. Duh.
If you want to see by yourself, just [download DBVisualizer Free](https://www.dbvis.com/download/), configure the Apache Hive driver, open a connection, and check the *Database Info* tab.

Now, DBVis is quite permissive with lame drivers, but it seems that LibreOffice is not.

You can try the [Cloudera Hive JDBC driver](http://www.cloudera.com/downloads.html) as an alternative. You just have to "register" -- i.e. leave your e-mail address -- to access the download URL; it's simpler to deploy than the Apache thing *(based on the Simba SDK, all Hive-specific JARs are bundled)* and it works with about any BI tool. So hopefully it works with LibreThing too.

Disclaimer: I wish the Apache distro had a proper JDBC driver, and anyone could use it instead of relying of "free" commercial software. But for now it's just a wish.

Comment: Thanks @Samson. That's really helpful insight. I see that the Cloudera Hive drivers are currently only packaged for Redhat and Suse (I'm using Ubuntu). The DbVisualizer tool is cool - I've not seen that before and, like you said, clearly identifies various unsupported methods.

Comment: Don't get fooled by the "packaging" stuff - it makes sense for ODBC *(native compilation of C code)* but not for JDBC *(just a bunch of portable JARs, you can compile them in Eclipse on Windows and use them later on Linux or AIX)*. Download **any** of the "JDBC packages", open the ZIP, choose between the JDBC 4.0-compliant and JDBC 4.1-compliant variant (depends on what LibreBureau supports), and drop the JARs somewhere on Windows and.or Linux.

Comment: @Alex, one more thing: the latest version of the Cloudera Impala JDBC driver has a bug -- in some specific configurations (i.e. with SSL enabled) it fails with bizarre messages about "sockets already open" at connect time. I suspect that it shares the same code base with the Hive driver. If you get bizarre messages yourself, try some older version...