# Datastax graphloader from hive using jdbc

Tags: graph, datastax, datastax-enterprise-graph

I have tried using:

```
Database.connection("jdbc:hive2://remote_hive:10000/db_name").driver(???).user("admin").password("admin_password")
```

which driver should i use to connect to hive?

Does anyone know if there is some source of API documentation?
Or does anyone knows of a better way then using dry run to debug?

the best link i could find is https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/dgl/dglJDBC.html

I simply don't know what should i check....

Comment: What do you mean by "hive"? Apache Hive, or something else??? Because the JDBC URL for connecting to Apache Hive clearly doesn't start with `jdbc:h2`

Comment: you right i meant hive, though don't know which driver should i supply. i tried "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver" but it does not work. guess that if this its the solution i need to put the jar file of the drivers somewhere on the server

Answer (score 0):

You have several possible JDBC drivers for Hive, but I doubt any of these is packaged with Cassandra...

- the reference is the **Apache driver**, of course (documented [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-JDBC)), but it has some issues: does not fully support the JDBC API (as explained in [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38299099/libreoffice-base-jdbc-connection-to-hive-returns-method-not-supported-when-exe)); exists in two flavors, one "scattered" *(has dependencies on several other `hive-*.jar` libs etc. etc.-- see post link above)* and one so-called "standalone" *(which still has dependencies on several `hadoop-*.jar` and Apache utils)*; has version compatibility issues i.e. the driver version must be equal or *older* than the HiveServer2 version
- a nice alternative is the **Cloudera driver** which is based on the Simba SDK (details in post link above); but remember that it is designed for Cloudera distros, so it may not be aligned with the latest Apache release  (and it may have bugs of its own)
- there is also the **DataDirect driver** that is bundled in a lot of commercial BI tools (from Oracle, IBM, MicroStrategy, etc) with an OEM license; but apart from the cost$ issue, last time I checked, it did not cover all Hive connectivity options *(maybe they bridged the gap now?)*

First step: download one or more JDBC driver(s).
Second step: "make friends" with the driver(s) *-- i.e. check out the CLASSPATH issues, URL syntax issues, etc --* with a JDBC utility such as DBVisualizer (see post link above, once again).
Third step: profit!

Comment: thanks man' but i meant on the dse graph loader, when i use the groovy script, which drivers are supported? can i add another drivers? hive is supported

Comment: does dse graph loader supports hive jdbc connection? if so how can i use it? , there is any API docs?